# Cannot launch Facebook Android App chat from android app using thread id

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to launch the android facebook app from my android app using a message's thread_id in order to show that specific chat. I am creating my intent as follows:

```
String uri = "fb://messaging/thread/thread?id=" + threadId; 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
```

Using this approach, the Facebook App is launched but contains the message "Something went wrong. Please try again."

It appears that I have an authorization issue as the stacktrace I get shows an `"OAuthException","code":1`. Logcat output is below. The app has logged in with the `permissions=[public_profile, user_friends, read_stream, email, installed, basic_info, read_mailbox]`. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
02-06 13:02:30.687: E/ActivityThread(14968): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.orca.notify.MessengerLoggedInUserProvider
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968): Exception during service
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: null
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968): {"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:232)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:202)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.NormalBatchController.a(NormalBatchController.java:43)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.MethodBatcherImpl$MethodBatchImpl.a(MethodBatcherImpl.java:541)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.MethodBatcherImpl$MethodBatchImpl.a(MethodBatcherImpl.java:166)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.MethodBatcherImpl$MethodBatchImpl$BatchResponseHandler.b(MethodBatcherImpl.java:282)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.MethodBatcherImpl$MethodBatchImpl$BatchResponseHandler.a(MethodBatcherImpl.java:251)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.MethodBatcherImpl$MethodBatchImpl$BatchResponseHandler.handleResponse(MethodBatcherImpl.java:231)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:325)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:151)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:103)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:241)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.MethodBatcherImpl$MethodBatchImpl.a(MethodBatcherImpl.java:213)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractBatch.a(AbstractBatch.java:42)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.WebServiceHandler.d(WebServiceHandler.java:226)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:35)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.orca.database.DbServiceHandler.d(DbServiceHandler.java:368)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:35)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.orca.cache.CacheServiceHandler.d(CacheServiceHandler.java:176)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.orca.server.AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.a(AbstractBlueServiceHandlerFilter.java:35)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.FilterChainLink.a(FilterChainLink.java:20)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:302)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:54)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:232)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 13:02:30.828: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(14968):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```